# Gil-less container for cython extension type

Tags: python, cython

I have a multithreaded cython application and would like to pass an extension type between threads that holds a pointer to a thread safe Circular buffer that also makes various calculations.

Is there any way to make a c++ container handle a Extension type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can just cast to void *, pass it into your container, then convert back to your extension type. It's up to you to ensure you still have a reference to it in order to not let the pointer being invalid.

Comment: I ended up wrapping shared_ptrs to extension types